# Reenable urllib3 warnings

Tags: python, urllib3

I have a portion of my code where I knowingly make an Insecure Request. So I disable warnings with

```
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
```

After that part, how do I reenable/reset `urllib3` warnings in my script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to programmatically reset all warnings, you can do:

```
import warnings
warnings.resetwarnings()
```

This will cause all of the urllib3 warnings (and all other warnings) to revert back to the default state.

The `urllib3.disable_warnings` helper is [a one-line wrapper](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/30e9855307aaa9f9f09651f2bbddeb7350eed666/urllib3/__init__.py#L92) around `warnings.simplefilter('ignore', category)`.

If you'd like to apply a specific category override yourself, you can do something like:

```
warnings.simplefilter('default', category)
```

More on warning filters here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#available-functions

Answer (score 4):

The `warnings` module has [a documentation section on temporarily ignoring warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings).  If you have one part of your code where you're making the insecure request, you can wrap that in a context:

```python
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore', urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
    # Run the rest of your code
```