# Ignore warning for certificate verification during HTTPS Rest call

Tags: python-3.x, rest, python-requests, warnings, urllib3

I know this has been asked and answered many times: [Reenable urllib3 warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50414913/reenable-urllib3-warnings),
[How to suppress warnings about lack of cert verification in a requests HTTPS call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767143/how-to-suppress-warnings-about-lack-of-cert-verification-in-a-requests-https-cal)

Even I had it working as well previously with below solution:

```
import requests

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

But since I had enabled extension for pyLint in VSCode it stopped working.(I know pyLint may not have impacted it but I have started facing this only after enabling pyLint extension)

So pyLint started complaining about "packages" is not there in "requests"

I have tried another solution being discussed in above posts, which is:

```
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

Which doesn't work as well.

Someone also suggested to use

```
requests.urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

instead of

```
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

but in my case it seems "requests" doesn't have "urllib3" inside it.

So is there any other way to ignore these warnings.

I am having below setup:

Python - 3.10.6
requests - 2.28.1
urllib3 - 1.26.12
pyLint extension for VSCode - v2022.4.0